# Using python to fix broken XML

Tags: python, xml

I have multiple xml files in which the tags are not closed properly. They are often moved to the next line.

**My XML**

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
<item id='my-img' href='images/dp.jpg' media-type='image/jpeg'/
>     
</note>
```

Is there any pythonic way of converting it to desired XML like below? :

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
<item id='my-img' href='images/dp.jpg' media-type='image/jpeg'/>     
</note>
```

I have tried using beautifulsoup. But it doesn't seem to format this properly.

Comment: A simple search and replace, of newline+> by >. If you provide some code, we might be able to help

Comment: beautifulsoup is meant for parsing not editing, You have to edit it as a text (string)

Comment: In this particular case it's probably not too hard to repair the damage. But whenever you have broken data like this, the important thing is to identify and eliminate the root cause - who broke the data in the first place?

Comment: @Stefan I don't have enough regex skills for selecting the whole tag. I started learning it recently. Would this type of regex work?  ^<.*\n>$

Comment: @Matiiss I know, But I have like 600+ files, I don't have strength to go and open all of those to just edit a single line.

Comment: @MichaelKay These are all batch of xml files which need to be rendered correctly. The program that renders doesn't like line break inside tags. Thus it keeps on crashing. I thought I could right a program that could edit and fix instances where tag end has moved to new line.

Comment: actually I think there is a different reason it crashes, the item tag is not closed with `</item>`

Comment: @Matiiss I did test.
__<item id='my-img' href='images/dp.jpg' media-type='image/jpeg'/>__ works. While
__<item id='my-img' href='images/dp.jpg' media-type='image/jpeg'/
\n>__ 
This doesn't. T_T

Comment: @HoneyBadger well my editor said that tag is not closed but ok

Comment: They aren't XML files, please don't think of them or refer to them as XML files. They are wannabe-XML files that didn't quite make the grade. The program that rejects them is doing the right thing; the data is bad and needs fixing (or returning to sender).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i could think of would be <strike>to remove line breaks entirely</strike>, load the xml and save a prettyfied version. The default repr only fixes the tags but keeps the format the same.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with open("file.xml","r") as f:
    xml_str = f.read();                   # Load file
    xml = bs(xml_str, "lxml")             # parse file 
with open("file.xml","w") as f:
    f.write(repr(xml))                    # write pretty file
```

Note: we are using the lxml parser which needs to be installed using

```
pip3 install lxml
```

Edit: no need to remove the line breaks

Comment: That shouldn't happen when using the "lxml" parser. Maybe you have `xml = bs(xml_str)` istead of `xml = bs(xml_str,"lxml")`

Comment: Please look at this screenshot. 
https://ibb.co/fNmnHgf

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on how many xml fields you need to fix and if there is a pattern in it. From what you put as an example, might be easier to use find and replace (for example using **regular expressions**).

Comment: Please consider providing an answer specific to the OP's code.